# How can i remove the options which are greater than the selected one in a select element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
jQuery("#vavCount select option").each(function() {
      if ($('#vavCount select ').is(':enabled')) {
        if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).val(), checkBoxIdAndDropdownValue) === -1) {
          $("#vavCount select option").each(function() {
            if ($(this).val()) > (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).val())) {
              jQuery(this).remove();
            }
          })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one" id="vavCount">
  <select name="" disabled="disabled" id="VAV_CountCheck" style="margin-left: 18px;width: 84px;">
    <option value="1025">5</option>
    <option value="1035">15</option>
    <option value="1040">20</option>
    <option value="1045">25</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much description, so here are three examples that may satisfy your objectives. The first one assumes that you're getting the comparison value from some other source (perhaps another form field). The second example select box trims its own values down once you select a value. The third uses a value found in an array.

```js
// First example uses an arbitrary value for the comparison

var checkBoxIdAndDropdownValue = 1039;

// Test to see if the select box is enabled first
if ($('#vavCount select').is(':enabled')) {
  // Loop once for each option
  $("#vavCount select option").each(function() {
    // If option value is greater, remove it from dropdown
    if ($(this).val() > checkBoxIdAndDropdownValue) {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  })
}


// Second example if you meant that you want to use
// the selected value of the dropdown to trim the options

var currentValue;

// When an item is selected
$('#vavCount2 select').change(function() {
  currentValue = $('#vavCount2 select').val();
  // Loop once for each option
  $("#vavCount2 select option").each(function() {
    // If the chosen option value is greater, remove it from dropdown
    if ($(this).val() > currentValue) {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  })
});


// Third example (!) if you are testing for a value in an array to trim the options

var matchingVal;
var valueArray = [1020, 1035, 1040, 2000];

// Test to see if the select box is enabled first
if ($('#vavCount3 select').is(':enabled')) {
  // Loop once for each option
  $("#vavCount3 select option").each(function() {
    // convert to an integer (only needed if array uses integers)
    var optionVal = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if (!matchingVal && valueArray.includes(optionVal)) {
      matchingVal = optionVal;
    }

    // If the matching value is greater, remove it from dropdown
    if (matchingVal && optionVal > matchingVal) {
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Example 1</h3>
<div class="one" id="vavCount">
  <select id="VAV_CountCheck" style="margin-left: 18px;width: 84px;">
    <option value="1025">5</option>
    <option value="1035">15</option>
    <option value="1040">20</option>
    <option value="1045">25</option>
  </select>
</div>

<h3>Example 2</h3>
<div class="one" id="vavCount2">
  <select id="VAV_CountCheck" style="margin-left: 18px;width: 84px;">
    <option value="1025">5</option>
    <option value="1035">15</option>
    <option value="1040">20</option>
    <option value="1045">25</option>
  </select>
</div>

<h3>Example 3</h3>
<div class="one" id="vavCount3">
  <select id="VAV_CountCheck" style="margin-left: 18px;width: 84px;">
    <option value="1025">5</option>
    <option value="1035">15</option>
    <option value="1040">20</option>
    <option value="1045">25</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for the description  but i am getting the option value from array how do i find the option value is present in array if present remove the options value grater than that value

Comment: Added a third example.

Comment: Did that work for you? If so, please upvote and accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: ya its worked for me thanks . i am looking for how to accept the answer i am not getting any option to accept the answer